# Tricky background removal for an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, background-image

friends!

I've been working on a project where we take tissue-cleared mice hearts and image them with a light sheet microscope to get the full organ. In reality, it sections the image to slices a few microns apart (depth-wise), so at the end you get a big OME-TIFF file with hundreds of those slices (a few GB).
These hearts have some fluorescent foci within the tissue that we want to count. I've attached a slice sample below.[image: How it looks like][image: I circled the foci in this image]

I did some manipulation on the image to get rid of a lot of background, but as you can see, this is not enough.

If you go through the images, it is very easy to pick out the foci, and a lot of slices are more obvious than others (some look like a chocolate chip cookie...), but manually counting is not an option.

To count the foci, I use an island-counter function that filters out islands that are too large and duplicated foci from the previous slices.

class IslandCounter_hist:

```
def counter(self, array,visited_prev):
    def in_array(h, w):
        return 0 <= h < len(array) and 0 <= w < len(array[0])

    def neighbours(node):
        a, b = node
        dir = [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)]
        return [(h, w) for h, w in [(a + i, b + j) for i, j in dir] if in_array(h, w)]

    def dfs(node,recursion):
        visited.add(node)
        recursion+=1
        for v in neighbours(node):
            if recursion==8000: #This one is arbitrary. Just because it can get stuck on big    chunks
                break
            if array[v[0]][v[1]]>0 and v not in visited:
                dfs(v,recursion)
                
    
    islands = 0
    dist_array=np.array([])
    visited = set()
    sub_visited=set()
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(array[0])):
            node = (i, j)
            recursion=0
            if array[i][j] >0 and node not in visited:
                dfs(node,recursion)
                if 9<=(len(visited)-len(sub_visited))<=264 and node not in visited_prev: 
                    dist_array=np.append(dist_array,len(visited)-len(sub_visited))
                    islands += 1
                    sub_visited=visited.copy()
                else:
                    sub_visited=visited.copy()

    return islands,visited,dist_array
```

The main challenge here is that there isn't a way to describe those foci. They can be low/high intensity, small or big etc. I manually counted a few hundreds with ImageJ to get some criteria for min/max pixel size area(the 9 and 264), but that is about it. It works well as a function, but gives way to much false positives because of excessive background.

I tried thresholding, but is gives either false positives or removing what I need. tried playing with the removal of the "walls", but failed. Tried some "fancy" OpenCV stuff like contouring, but it was all over the place.
Frankly, I just need to get rid of the background without losing anything inside the organ itself. Any additional cleaning steps will be appreciated or any fixing of the function.

Thanks so much!

Comment: This is a nasty one. I'd try separating the big object first, to get rid of all the splatter. Try a morpholical operation (growing) and binarisation to close the shape, then extract contours. Remove everything thats not in the area of the largest contour. That should get rid of the background.

Comment: Finding all the small spots inside the object looks even harder. The single ones on black you could detect with contours again, but those close to inside edge on the right ? The rightmost one is the worst...

Comment: Did you aquire the images in different color channels which could provide support, like colocalization of foci/background in different channels? Are single foci visible in multiple imaged layers?

Comment: I did. There are two channels - one with foci and one without. The images I've posted are after I normalize the two channels to smooth the background.

Comment: Since you mentioned ImageJ: Sometimes a rolling ball background removal is helpful if the background is inhomogeneous. I tried it already on the image you provided and unfortunately it didn't look good. Was the example image already processed? Not an option for the obtained results but would you be able to label the foci differently? It would always be best to optimize the imaging procedure before doing the real imaging.

Comment: Thank you for trying. The image is processed to remove as much background as possible without hurting the foci visibility. Unfortunately no, this is the best image contrast I can make. I struggled a lot with this before reaching out...but you just confirmed my belief that this approach will not yield good results. I resorted to counting everything manually after maximum background cleaning. What a mess. The initial thought was that the foci are significantly brighter than anything else...but that was untrue...would have been a lot easier to work with.